# Which FLOSS Python CMS for video sharing in a school?

Tags: cms, video, python, sharing, education

I have an university project in which we develop a **video sharing system for schools**. Our central use cases are as follows:

- The system has to **manage videos** (and associated arbitrary metadata)
  Where management includes uploading, transcoding, browsing (by metadata) and playing
- The system has to implement a **3-tier release process**:

  - pupils may add videos to the system
  - teachers may approve added videos, publishing them to other pupils
  - administrators may revoke the approval of published videos

The system needs to be developed in an agile fashion, oriented on Extreme Programming. As a result, the system needs to be implemented in a programming language, the developers are familiar with. The biggest overlap in competences of the developers is Python, so with additional functional requirements to be expected:

- The system needs to be implemented and extensible in **Python**.

The system needs to be released to the general public, so

- The system and all components need to be licensed as **open source**.

Which extensible open source Python CMS, supports video content and a role-based workflow?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [**"Community Edition"** of the **Mediacore** video sharing platform](http://mediacorecommunity.org/) that is open source (Core: GPL, Frontend: MIT, Plugins: various). It claims to be a general "video, audio and podcast publication platform written in Python (2.4, 2.5, 2.6, or 2.7)." while the commercial hosted version available at Mediacore.com is specifically designed for use in schools and universities. It is advertised as being a "fully managed version of MediaCore with cloud delivery, mobile support, and a huge number of improvements." but there is a [feature comparison page, listing further differences between Mediacore.com und Mediacore CE](http://mediacorecommunity.org/#comparison). The [Mediacore-Community GitHub repository](https://github.com/mediacore/mediacore-community) shows recent development activity (5 days ago) and a reasonable amount community interest (273 Stars, 73 Forks) at the time of writing. There are some [Mediacore plugins being developed at GitHub](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=mediacore&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories), including [an automated transcoder using ffmpeg](https://github.com/valeriominetti/mediacore-ffmpeg-bot) and the [video.js HTML5 media player](https://github.com/qtheuret/MediaCore-video.js-player). Mediacore is based on [Pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) and uses [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) Templates, so extensibility should exist to some degree.